# Fatal Error Class 'WP_Widget_Pages' not found in /home/****/public_html/wp-includes/class-wp-widget-factory.php

Tags: fatal-error

So I am not well versed in wordpress and had this site built for a friend and it worked just fine for years. I tried to login to make some changes for him with /wp-admin and got the WSOD. I tried stopping all plugins, reverting to the standard theme and nothing worked. The website still works fine I just cant log in to it. So I turned on debuging through ftp and this is what I got.

Stack trace:
#0 /home/***/public_html/wp-includes/widgets.php(115): WP_Widget_Factory->register('WP_Widget_Pages')
#1 /home/****/public_html/wp-includes/widgets.php(1809): register_widget('WP_Widget_Pages')
#2 /home/****/public_html/wp-includes/class-wp-hook.php(307): wp_widgets_init('')
#3 /home/****/public_html/wp-includes/class-wp-hook.php(331): WP_Hook->apply_filters(NULL, Array)
#4 /home/****/public_html/wp-includes/plugin.php(474): WP_Hook->do_action(Array)
#5 /home/****/public_html/wp-settings.php(592): do_action('init')
#6 /home/****/public_html/wp-config.php(119): require_once('/home/zic97gker...')
#7 /home/****/public_html/wp-load.php(50): require_once('/home/zic97gker...')
#8 /home/****/public_html/wp-blog-header.php(13): require_once('/home/zic97gker...')
#9 /home/****/public_html/index.php(24 in /home/zic97gkeryai/public_html/wp-includes/class-wp-widget-factory.php on line 61
[12-Apr-2022 18:48:07 UTC] PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught Error: Class 'WP_Widget_Pages' not found in /home/zic97gkeryai/public_html/wp-includes/class-wp-widget-factory.php:61

Any help would be great!

Comment: have you edited/modified files in the `wp-admin` or `wp-includes` folder? Or removed/added new files?

Comment: I have not. He was having issues with a hack/redirect. I found that and deleted it. Thats all I did.

Comment: And your comment got me thinking. Those two folders should be completely untouched so I should be safe to delete the contents and reupload them. I did that and lo and behold, it works perfect now. Thanks for making me think this through!

Comment: can you post that as an answer below?

Answer (score 0):

And your comment got me thinking. Those two folders should be completely untouched so I should be safe to delete the contents and re-upload them. I did that and lo and behold, it works perfect now. Thanks for making me think this through!